# Regex to match multiple emails separated by space or puncts

Tags: php, regex, email-validation

I need a regex to match multiple email address separated by space(s) and/or puncts. The email addresses are into a string. I'm trying this, but it doesn't works

```
^(\s[[:punct:]])*([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}){1}(\s[[:punct:]])*$
```

Text could be like this:

> abcd@abcd.ef, abcd@abcd.ef abcd@abcd.ef

Or even like this

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit abcd@abcd.ef amet, consectetur, abcd@abcd.ef, adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consectetur fringilla mi ac dignissim. Nulla at est quam. abcd@abcd.ef Sed enim.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: split/explode the string w.r.t. `,`; then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: See also [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Comment: I've seen that. I need to catch every email address from a text to manipulate it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace the ^ and $ anchors with something that doesn't force the email to be both first and last in the line...

like \b (word boundry)

```
\b(\s[[:punct:]])*([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}){1}(\s[[:punct:]])*\b
```

or nothing at all ?

```
(\s[[:punct:]])*([a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}){1}(\s[[:punct:]])*
```

http://rubular.com/r/AMnr2kzp09

or simply

```
(\b[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}\b)
```

since the {1} was restricting the number of emails you could match between ^ and $